# RegEx for Removing First Two Segments and Leaving the Last Two Segments

Tags: regex, parsing

I am working with a third party system that will take a RegEx to parse data within their system.  I have not wrote RegEx in many years and I am stuck.  The original data all starts with 2 or 3 characters (building), followed by a space dash space, then by another 2 or 3 characters (department), then space dash space, the user's full name, space dash space, and finally their phone extension.  I want to end up with the user's fully name, space dash space, and their extension.

The max character allotment for the field in the system is 26 characters.  I would rather trim the name than cut off the 4-digit extension, if that is possible.

All the data is varied, but looks similar to these examples.

```
RB - HS - John Doe - 8400
MCH - SOC - Jane Smith - 5200
```

I need the data to look like:

```
John Doe - 8400
Jane Smith - 5200
```

Comment: Does the system let you write some kind of substitution operation with captures?

Comment: @rici No it is just a match option

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Find: ^.* - (.{1,19}).*?( - [0-9]{4})$
Replace: $1$2
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Rv2aWv/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   -                       ' - '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .{1,19}                  any character except \n (between 1 and
                             19 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     -                       ' - '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{4}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: This is a great option, however it does not allow me to use a substitution/replacement option.  I need to use a Match option.  I have been playing with Branch Reset Groups, but haven't been able to get it quire right.

Comment: @WCIT There is no way to achieve that with branch reset groups.  You stuck forever then.